# Create an SDMX file in R

Tags: r, sdmx

I do not have any code to post, but just a question.
There are several tools I am aware of to read SDMX files in R (an SDMX is an XML file for exchanging statistical data) like for instance

https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx

https://github.com/amattioc/SDMX

but does anyone know a way to export some data to an SDMX format for dissemination?
Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a ‘pure’ R solution, but the Python [`sdmx1`](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io) package is fully usable through [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/), and allows to programmatically generate SDMX objects and then serialize them as SDMX-ML (XML). For example:

```r
# Use reticulate to import the Python package
> library(reticulate)
> sdmx <- import("sdmx")

# Create an (empty) DataMessage object
> msg <- sdmx$message$DataMessage()

# Convert to XML
> xml <- sdmx$to_xml(msg, pretty_print = TRUE)

# Write to file using the built-in R method
# The Python 'bytes' object must be decoded to a string
> write(xml$decode(), file = "message.xml")
```

This gives output like:

```xml
<mes:GenericData xmlns:com="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common" xmlns:data="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/structurespecific" xmlns:str="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/structure" xmlns:mes="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message" xmlns:gen="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic" xmlns:footer="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message/footer" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <mes:Header>
    <mes:Test>false</mes:Test>
  </mes:Header>
</mes:GenericData>
```

For more information on authoring more complex messages using `sdmx1`, there is a page [“HOWTO Generate SDMX-ML from Python objects”](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/create.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please make a reprex? It would make my life easier!

Comment: Sorry—I'm not much of an R user, and thus don't even know what "a reprex" is! The code in the first snippet _is_ complete, if that's what you mean, and will work so long as you have reticulate (R) and sdmx1 (Python) installed.